# How to make locators in Selenium generic using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

I am trying to write a code for below scenario. I have an enum file with all the ids and xpaths of a page which returns

```
    public enum idrepo {
    logingid("login_id"),
    pwdID("pwd_id"),
    SaveButtonXpath("/savebutton");

    String id;
    private idrepo(String Id)
    {
       this.id = Id;
    }
    public String getValue(){
    return id;
    }
```

Now i want to write a test case like below

```
getDriver().getElementAndClick(logingid).click();
```

I want to avoid using By.ID By.Xpath or By.Class etc and pass the element directly.

Is it possible for me use Interface concept here? Like create an object for locators and use them?

Comment: In my opinion, it should be a static class instead of enum.

Comment: You can go with page factory.

Comment: @Buaban am avoiding static methods or classes as am trying to make it purely object oriented.

Comment: @Murthi in Page factory can i make a separate class for only the Locators? if so how shall call it?

Comment: Yes, you can create separate class for only the locators and call it in test. For example, class homepage { @FindBy(id="loginID") public WebElement InputLogin; } and in your script you can call like  homepage hp=PageFactory.initElements(driver, homepage.class); hp.inputLogin.senkeys("value");

Comment: @Ashu123 (Static method is OOP, I'm curious why do you need to avoid it). You can add more code and more complexity to make Enum to return text or by. But all the locators are static and always shareable. In my opinion, static class is the best option.